How can i use the enum value in the action methods?
public enum ImgExt
{
    jpeg,
    png,
    svg,
    gif,
}

I want the ImgExt enum value in dynamically as per the request in action method
public static GetImg(Guid Id,"enumType" ImgExt) // here value will be populated dynamically as per the request


How do you want your request to look like? GetImg/Guid/jpeg or GetImg/guid/0 ?

what is the problem with static GetImg(Guid id, ImgExt imgExt)?

public static GetImg() needs void or a return type?

As a side-note, I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions. But more generally, this question isn't clear in terms of what you're asking, or what the "action method" is - you haven't provided us with any context.

If you want it to be working with the string value and the numeric value then you can use the enum member attribute [EnumMember(Value = "jpeg")] so your enum could look like:
public enum ImageType 
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "jpeg")]
    Jpeg,
    [EnumMember(Value = "png")]
    Png,
    [EnumMember(Value = "svg")]
    Svg,
    [EnumMember(Value = "gif")]
    Gif
}

Then you can use it in your method like this:
     [HttpGet("getimg/{guid}/{imageType}")]
     public IActionResult GetImg(Guid guid, ImageType imageType)

